# Google Play Game Services C++ SDK does not find NativeSdkEntryPoints java class

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x, google-play-services

The Google Play Games Services works well, but there comes following error after creating GameServices object. I'm using SDK with cocos2d-x.

Java Activity is initialized within JNI_OnLoad.
Creating the GameServices object is initialized as descripted in Googles C++ SDK docs.

Google Play Game Services C++ SDK 1.2
Google Play Services Revision 20
Android NDK 9d

```
10-22 08:07:43.474: E/GamesNativeSDK(26078): Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.CompanyName.MyApp/app_.gpg.classloader/921cd45b6e4d26e0809d5e163b7327ee.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
```

Is this error critical?
And how can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, it's critical, and it looks like you aren't including the necessary library in your package.

Comment: I have Android library project for Google Play added, and Google Play Game Services C++ SDK included. I would guess that Java class which wasn't found, should be inside the Android library project or at least included there..

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with NativeSdkEntryPoints being missing. I'm using the latest google-play-services_lib and can log in to google play if I use java, but it doesn't find NativeSdkEntryPoints. Examining the jar file, the class does not seem to exist at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not critical and you can ignore it.

From much experimentation myself after getting the same error message, the classes do not appear to exist in google-play-services jar, but they are not required anyway. All the normal services function correctly through the cpp lib despite the error message.

Comment: Do you get callback for RealTimeMultiplayer().SendReliableMessage(room, participant, callback) function? For me, GPGS informs in log that reliable message was successful, but the callback doesn't get called. Callback was created with lambda, like: [this](gpg::MultiplayerStatus const &result) {}

Comment: Sorry I'm not using the real time multiplayer service. I'm using achievements, leaderboards, cloud messaging and cloud saved games (snapshots). All of which function correctly (including callbacks) despite the reported error about NativeSdkEntryPoints.